# Gnome terminal not working in Ubuntu GNOME 17.04

Tags: gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

I recently erased and reinstalled Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 on my laptop (Because I encrypted my home folder with the first installation and wasn't able to remove the encryption). The first time, everything worked perfectly. The second time, things were working well for a while. But today, I installed screenfetch and ran it thrice, after which, I switched off my laptop. I switched it on five hours later, and I wasn't able to start the terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+T. I tried opening it from the list of applications, but it just showed Terminal loading on the top bar and closed. I read online that screenfetch can cause this problem, but when I used screenfetch with the first installation, nothing like this happened. I tried all of those locale settings solutions, but none worked. For now, I'm only able to use XTerm, and I'm only able to run GNOME Terminal by typing the command `dbus-launch gnome-terminal` in XTerm. Is there any way to fix this? Because I really like GNOME Terminal and I don't want to have to reinstall again.

SIDE NOTE: I made a temporary user account, and tried running GNOME Terminal in that account. And it worked as it was supposed to.

UPDATE: When I try starting terminal from Xterm by typing `gnome-terminal`, it gives the following error:

`Error constructing proxy server for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Error calling StartServiceByName for org.gnome.Terminal: Timeout was reached`

UPDATE 2: I ran the command `dbus-update-activation-environment --all` in Xterm, and Terminal started working again. But after rebooting, Terminal stopped working again. Even if i type the command again.

UPDATE 3: Typing the following command in Xterm gets GNOME Terminal working properly again, but it requires me to type this every time I reboot.

`sudo localedef -v -c -i en_US -f UTF-8 en_US.UTF-8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open `gedit` and see if it shows a transparent editing window. This may be a similar symptom as your `terminal` symptom.

Delete this file in your home directory and see if `terminal` works as before...

```
cd # change directory to home
rm -i .xinputrc # delete file with prompt
```

The file will recreate itself when required.

**Update #1:**

```
cd # change directory to home
cd .gconf/apps # change directory
mv gnome-terminal gnome-terminal.HOLD # rename folder
```

Now retry to start gnome-terminal.

Comment: Gedit was fine when I tried it. Also, when I executed the command you gave, it said that the file .xinputrc doesn't exist.

Comment: Have you edited any of the .bash* or .profile files in your home directory?

Comment: I'll update my answer.

Comment: I actually gave up and reinstalled Ubuntu GNOME, because I had lots of college work, and I wasn't able to find a solution. But, I'll accept your answer anyway. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

you need to add dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all into ~/.xinitrc

or download scripts from followings

https://github.com/3togo/useful_bash_scripts/blob/master/fix_gnome_terminal_dbus_problem

Comment: I ran `dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all` on the command line and then I could start gnome-terminal. I did not have a ~/.xinitrc, so I created it and entered dbus-update-activation-environment --systemd --all into it; then I restarted my session and now everything works fine. (Earlier I found that I also needed to add export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority to my .bashrc file.) FWIW, I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and xfce4 (with tigervncserver). Thanks Eli!

Answer (score 0):

I clobbered gnome-terminal while using xemacs over ssh; I wish I could be more specific.  However, the only way to repair gnome-terminal was to backup my user account with tar and recreate my account.  I wasted many hours trying to fix it before giving up and using brute force.

Comment: I don't thin kit's necessary to delete the whole profile.

Comment: It's better than what OP did as he/she reinstalled the entire OS.